# How to use Mule ajax connector in High Availability mode?

Tags: ajax, mule, high-availability

Trying to run the application on two different instances of Mule server but on the same machine

In this case obviously the first instance succeeds to bind but the other one fails.

```
<ajax:connector name="ajaxConn" serverUrl="http://0.0.0.0:1234/test" 
    resourceBase="${app.home}/test" doc:name="Ajax"/>
```

What would be ideal way to handle this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is tipically fixed using a [Mule Domain](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/shared-resources), however the ajax connector does not support domains and therefor your best change is using a different port.

Comment: Thanks. Wanted to avoid a change in a mule-config. But if there is not a better way, then have to go this way.

Comment: Other options are don't use 0.0.0.0 in both connectors, use system properties or docker containers.